# Google Cloud Dataflow application that uses JPA 2 and Hibernate won't run with BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner. Fails to find persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Google Cloud Dataflow application that as part of a transform records some information to a MySQL database through JPA 2 and Hibernate. When running this application with the DirectPipelineRunner it locates the persistence.xml and runs fine.

However, when I try to make use of the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner the persistence context won't initialize because it can't find the persistence.xml. Maybe it can't be loaded from the CLASSPATH? The message being that the only persistence unit named in the persistence.xml isn't found.

Has anyone successfully used JPA 2 and Hibernate with a Dataflow application? If so, what hoops did you have to jump through to get it working when using the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner?

Comment: Hibernate by default looks for the persistence.xml file in potentially many locations. You may want to confirm that the jars that get uploaded contain META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: If you add the flag --workerLogLevelOverrides=org.hibernate#TRACE that should give you much more detailed output related to Hibernate (you may need to configure JBoss logging to go to SLF4J or JUL to get the Hibernate logging to appear, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate by default looks for the persistence.xml file in potentially many locations. You may want to confirm that the jars that get uploaded contain META-INF/persistence.xml.

If you add the flag

> --workerLogLevelOverrides=org.hibernate#TRACE

, that should give you much more detailed output related to Hibernate (you may need to configure JBoss logging to go to SLF4J or JUL to get the Hibernate logging to appear, [docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html)/…).